# Need help solving a problem on arranging balls

Tags: discrete-mathematics

One of my friends gave me an interesting problem yesterday...Please omit the first four lines...start from the second paragraph...

[image]

[image]

What is the underlying principle that affects the fifth line?How to do it?

Thanks a lot in advance!!

Comment: imagine holding on to F G and H and turning the whole apparatus upside down.  F,  G and H must be in positions that make A, B and C perfectly horizontal

Answer (score 1):

Yeah...found out the solution yesterday....nice problem...!!

[image]

[image]